# Why javascript code not work when I use styled class in my code?

Tags: javascript, class, checkbox

```
<label for="q11"><input type="checkbox" class="styled" value=" Good" name="q11[]" id="q11_1">Good</label>
<label for="q11"><input type="checkbox" class="styled" value=" Poor" name="q11[]" id="q11_2">Poor</label>
<label for="q11"><input type="checkbox" class="styled" value=" Good" name="q11[]" id="q11_1">Good</label>
<label for="q11"><input type="checkbox" class="styled" value=" Poor" name="q11[]" id="q11_2">Poor</label>
```

Here is my code code I want some thing like this. Means when I check one checkbox the other checkbox should be unchech.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="styled" onclick="document.getElementById(q11_2).checked=false;" value="Transfer of risk > Poor" name="q11[]" id="q11_1">Poor</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="styled" onclick="document.getElementById(q11_1).checked=false;" value="Transfer of risk > Poor" name="q11[]" id="q11_2">Poor</label>
```

But the problem is this when i use styled class this code not work.

```
onclick="document.getElementById(q11_1).checked=false
```

but when i remove styled class it works properly. 
My style class code is this.

```
            if(inputs[a].checked == true) {
                if(inputs[a].type == "checkbox") {
                    position = "0 -" + (checkboxHeight*2) + "px";
                    span[a].style.backgroundPosition = position;
                } else {
                    position = "0 -" + (radioHeight*2) + "px";
                    span[a].style.backgroundPosition = position;
                }
            }
            inputs[a].parentNode.insertBefore(span[a], inputs[a]);
            inputs[a].onchange = Custom.clear;
            if(!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
                span[a].onmousedown = Custom.pushed;
                span[a].onmouseup = Custom.check;
            } else {
                span[a].className = span[a].className += " disabled";
            }
        }
    }
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
        if(inputs[a].className == "styled") {
            option = inputs[a].getElementsByTagName("option");
            active = option[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            textnode = document.createTextNode(active);
            for(b = 0; b < option.length; b++) {
                if(option[b].selected == true) {
                    textnode = document.createTextNode(option[b].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                }
            }
            span[a] = document.createElement("span");
            span[a].className = "select";
            span[a].id = "select" + inputs[a].name;
            span[a].appendChild(textnode);
            inputs[a].parentNode.insertBefore(span[a], inputs[a]);
            if(!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
                inputs[a].onchange = Custom.choose;
            } else {
                inputs[a].previousSibling.className = inputs[a].previousSibling.className += " disabled";
            }
        }
    }
    document.onmouseup = Custom.clear;
},
pushed: function() {
    element = this.nextSibling;
    if(element.checked == true && element.type == "checkbox") {
        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*3 + "px";
    } else if(element.checked == true && element.type == "radio") {
        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*3 + "px";
    } else if(element.checked != true && element.type == "checkbox") {
        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight + "px";
    } else {
        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight + "px";
    }
},
check: function() {
    element = this.nextSibling;
    if(element.checked == true && element.type == "checkbox") {
        this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
        element.checked = false;
    } else {
        if(element.type == "checkbox") {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*2 + "px";
        } else {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*2 + "px";
            group = this.nextSibling.name;
            inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
                if(inputs[a].name == group && inputs[a] != this.nextSibling) {
                    inputs[a].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
                }
            }
        }
        element.checked = true;
    }
},

    clear: function() {
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var b = 0; b < inputs.length; b++) {
        if(inputs[b].type == "checkbox" && inputs[b].checked == true && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*2 + "px";
        } else if(inputs[b].type == "checkbox" && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
        } else if(inputs[b].type == "radio" && inputs[b].checked == true && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*2 + "px";
        } else if(inputs[b].type == "radio" && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
        }
    }
},
choose: function() {
    option = this.getElementsByTagName("option");
    for(d = 0; d < option.length; d++) {
        if(option[d].selected == true) {
            document.getElementById("select" + this.name).childNodes[0].nodeValue = option[d].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
```

}
window.onload = Custom.init;

Comment: What do you mean by "styled class"? And you are missing "" around your ids, like getElemntById('id')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to quote the identifier.

```
onclick="document.getElementById('q11_2').checked=false"
```

Also, you might want to escape the `>` to `&gt;` in your `value` attribute.

Comment: the problem is not due to this because i use this in other simple checkboxes to test

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
document.forms['foo'].bar[0].checked=false;
```

Comment: yah but it also not work when i use styled class, otherwise work

Comment: CSS shouldn't be an issue if you're naming everything properly. If the other guy's suggestion of quoting the identifier `('q11_2')` doesn't work would you mind sharing your CSS?

Answer (score 1):

There could be some error in your style class code, due to which your checkbox event is not working properly. You should test this code in firebug or other debugging tool.